# DynamicGeoGraphics rendering error when AspectRatio is given, and the output does not match ImageSize

Tags: bugs, geographics

Here's a minimal example.

```
gm = GeoMarker[{{42.34, -71.08}, {42.35, -71.07}, {42.36, -71.06}}];

DynamicGeoGraphics[gm,AspectRatio->1]
```

Since GeoGraphics does give the proper map, something like this,

```
DynamicGeoGraphics[gm, Options[GeoGraphics[gm, AspectRatio->1], PlotRange]]
```

renders properly but the ImageSize differs,

```
ImageDimensions@Rasterize@DynamicGeoGraphics[gm,Options[GeoGraphics[gm,AspectRatio->1,ImageSize->{600,600}],PlotRange]] 

-> {579,579}


ImageDimensions@Rasterize@DynamicGeoGraphics[gm,ImageSize->{600,600},First@Options[GeoGraphics[gm,AspectRatio->1,ImageSize->{600,600}],PlotRange]]

-> {579,579}

ImageDimensions@Rasterize@DynamicGeoGraphics[gm, ImageSize -> {600, 600}]
-> {515, 696}
```

Is this a bug? Or is there some hidden option I'm not considering?